# Delphi webbrowser videostream and disable webbroswer clicking

Tags: delphi, video, web, streaming

Im working on a project where I need to stream a television Channel and at the same time increment some variables by pressing keys.
With the webbrowser I cant press those keys because the project is focusing the browser and not the form and I dunno how to disable it.
I would also like to know how to disable the scrollbars on TwebBrowser, i've tried many codes but none worked.

Comment: Show the code you're having trouble.

Comment: Are you looking for the form's `KeyPreview` property?

Comment: Also, "web browser clicking" and "web browser keyboard pressing" are two different topics with different solutions, so should be asked as two separate questions, as well as disabling scroll bars should be a third question.